# I have created trigger but not able to iterates final values

Tags: apex, trigger

[26]|DEBUG|ERROR:System.StringException: Invalid id: test@gmail.com

```
trigger AppLeadCreation on alu_Application__c (before insert, after update) {

    Map<Id,Lead> mapLeads = new Map<Id,Lead>([SELECT Id, Email FROM Lead]);
    Map<Id,String> mapIdsWithLeadEmail = new Map<Id,String>();
    Map<Id,String> mapIdsWithAppEmail = new Map<Id,String>();
    Map<Id,Id> mapAppIdsEmailIds = new Map<Id,Id>();
    System.debug('mapLeads'+mapLeads);

    for(Lead le : mapLeads.values()){       
        mapIdsWithLeadEmail.put(le.Id, le.Email);       
    }
    System.debug('mapIdsWithLeadEmail'+mapIdsWithLeadEmail);

    for(alu_Application__c app : trigger.new){
         mapIdsWithAppEmail.put(app.Id, app.Email__c);        
    }
    System.debug('mapIdsWithAppEmail'+mapIdsWithAppEmail);
    try{
        for(Id tmp : mapIdsWithAppEmail.KeySet()){
            System.debug('AA >>'+tmp);
            if(mapIdsWithLeadEmail.ContainsKey(mapIdsWithAppEmail.get(tmp))){                
                mapAppIdsEmailIds.put(tmp,mapIdsWithLeadEmail.get(tmp));
            }
        }
    }Catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('ERROR:' + e);
    }
    System.debug('mapAppIdsEmailIds'+mapAppIdsEmailIds); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your map is of type Id,Id

```
Map<Id,Id> mapAppIdsEmailIds = new Map<Id,Id>();
```

But here you are passing a string Email address

```
mapAppIdsEmailIds.put(tmp,mapIdsWithLeadEmail.get(tmp));
```

So change you map type to Id, String

```
Map<Id,String> mapAppIdsEmailIds = new Map<Id,String>();
```

And it will work.

Code to map lead with application

```
for(Lead le : mapLeads.values()){       
        mapIdsWithLeadEmail.put(le.Email, le.Id);       
    }
for(alu_Application__c app : trigger.new){
         mapIdsWithAppEmail.put(app.Email__c, app.Id);        
    }
    System.debug('mapIdsWithAppEmail'+mapIdsWithAppEmail);
    try{
        for(Id tmp : mapIdsWithAppEmail.KeySet()){
            if(mapIdsWithLeadEmail.ContainsKey(tmp)){                
                mapAppIdsEmailIds.put(mapIdsWithAppEmail.get(tmp),mapIdsWithLeadEmail.get(tmp));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66277/discussion-on-answer-by-tushar-sharma-i-have-created-trigger-but-not-able-to-ite).